# Unable to Add a Chart to Excel Workbook

Tags: ruby, excel, charts, rubygems

I am using the `writeexcel` gem.

The following is my code snippet:

```
workbook = WriteExcel.new("graphTest.xls")

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheetname = "Test")

chart = workbook.add_chart(
  :type => "Chart::column",
  :name => "Chart",
  :embedded => 1
  )
```

and I get the following error:

> undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Full error:

```
/Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/writeexcel-1.0.5/lib/writeexcel/chart.rb
:79:in 'factory': undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/writeexcel-1.0.5/lib/writee
xcel/workbook.rb:334:in 'add_chart'
        from excelGraph.rb:18:in '<main>'
```

Why am I getting this error message if I am taking an example straight from the gem documentation found [here](http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#add_chart)?

Comment: The example code here https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel works, just tested.

Comment: The chart examples mentioned above can be found [here](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The, "Gotcha," found within your code snippet is the capitalization of `column` in `Chart::column`:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart(
  :type => "Chart::Column", #capitalized
  :name => "Chart",
  :embedded => 1
  )
```

instead of

```
chart = workbook.add_chart(
  :type => "Chart::column", #all lowercase
  :name => "Chart",
  :embedded => 1
  )
```